# Initialise mongodb replica set never completing

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to intialise a mongodb replica set but whenever I add the new node it never makes it past state 3 (RECOVERING). Here is a snapshot from rs.status():

```
rs0:OTHER> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-27T14:09:21.973Z"),
    "myState" : 3,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "10.0.1.184:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 6899,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1430143759, 9),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-04-27T14:09:19Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-04-27T14:09:20.133Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-04-27T14:09:20.160Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1430127299, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-04-27T09:34:59Z"),
            "configVersion" : 109483
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.0.1.119:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 6899,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-04-27T14:09:20.133Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-04-27T14:09:20.166Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "configVersion" : 109483
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "10.0.1.179:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 3,
            "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
            "uptime" : 15651,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1430136863, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-04-27T12:14:23Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "configVersion" : 109483,
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Occasionally the infoMessage "could not find member to sync from" is visible on the new node. I note that the oplog on the current primary is only 0.12 hours (1.7GB) and that it is taking approx. 2 hours to copy over the majority of the dataset (as seen by network usage).

Is it correct to assume that the oplog must be greater than this 2 hour period for the initial sync to complete successfully?

Comment: The oplog window is an estimate, but yes - your oplog has to be sufficiently large to hold all of the write traffic that occurs during the data copy phase of the initial sync. This can be confirmed by searching your 10.0.1.179:27017 for "too stale to catch up", an indication that you have fallen off of the oplog.

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @kommradHomer - Yes thank-you. Our data throughput was too HIGH for the default OPLOG size. Increasing the OPLOG to 50GB allowed the sync to complete.

Comment: @MarcF i'm glad you are done with it. Would you answer your own question for future generations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed necessary for the oplog to be LARGER (in time) than the expected time to synchronise the data between two replicas. Disk is cheap so we increased our OPLOG to 50GB and restarted the sync, worked first time.